# Angularjs ng-change and ng-repeat not properly working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In ng-change the selected value  is not setting up in the ngchange function. 
First time when I select a value its setting up as null,  and again I try to select an another value, its setting the value of the previous selected value.

```
    var ngInitParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
    var firstVarId= Model.Variants.First().ProductId;
    var firstVarName= Model.Variants.First().Name;

    <section id="@inPageNavigationID" ng-controller="prodSpecsCtrl as main"
             ng-init="main.init('@firstVarId', '@firstVarName')">
        <div class="container" ng-init="main.loadSelect('@ngInitParams')">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 fieldset">
                        <div class="form__item ">
                            <div>
                                <select class="-dropdown--two-columns"  name="productvariants" id="sel1" data-placeholder="@selectOptionVal" ng-model="variant.ProductId" 
                                        ng-change="main.load('{{variant.ProductId}}','{{(main.JsonVariants.Variants | filter: {ProductId:variant.ProductId})[0].Name}}')">
                                        <option value="" disabled>Select Model</option> 
                                        <option ng-repeat="variant in main.JsonVariants.Variants" value="{{variant.ProductId}}" selected="@firstVariantId" data-option-header="{{variant.CatalogCode}}">{{variant.Name}}</option>
                                </select>
                                <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      <section>


        this.init = function (varId, varName) {
            this.load(varId, varName);
        }
        this.loadSelect = function (strjson) {
            self.JsonVariants = JSON.parse(strjson);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an ng-change within a select.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZhJbVfPRCLoeFwYoi3Mp?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <select ng-model="item" ng-change="changed(item)" ng-options="item.Name for item in items"></select>
 <p>ID:{{selected.ID}} Name: {{selected.Name}}</p>
 <p>You Selected: {{selected}}</p>
</body>
```

And Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.items = [];
 $scope.selected = {};

 $scope.changed = function(item) {
  $scope.selected = item;
 }

 function setupItems() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var item = {ID: i, Name: "Item " + i}
   $scope.items.push(item);
 }
}  
setupItems();
});
```

Comment: I have updated with the code i have used. I have to pass name and productid  in ng-change - function

Comment: can you help me out

Comment: I updated my answer, try implementing select options using ng-options. This way, by passing your "variant" object into your main.load function, it will include all of its properties.